# How it calculate size of array using pointer to array?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, sizeof, dereference

I have this following code, which has pointer variable pointer to an 2D array.

```
int main()
{
    int (*ptr)[2][3];
    printf("%u\n", sizeof(ptr)); // ---> give size of pointer = 8
    printf("%u\n", sizeof(*ptr)); // ---> give size of array = 24, how it works adding * to ptr gives array size

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(*ptr)` gives you the size of what `ptr` points to, which is an array of 2×3 ints.  So it should be the same as `int a[2][3]; sizeof(a)`, as it looks like it is.

Comment: do you mean size (24 bytes) or rather shape (2-by-3) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the conversion specifier `%zu` with values returned by the operator `sizeof` that have the type `size_t`.

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(ptr)); 
       ^^^^^
```

If you have a pointer like

```
T *p;
```

where `T` is some type then the expression `*p` has the type `T`. So `sizeof( *p )` is equivalent to `sizeof( T )`.

This declaration

```
int (*ptr)[2][3];
```

declares a pointer to the array type `int[2][3]`; You could rewrite the declaration with using a typedef the following way

```
typedef int T[2][3];
T *ptr;
```

So the expression `sizeof( *ptr )`  is equivalent to the expression `sizeof( int[2][3] )`.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(ptr)` is giving the size of the poiter itself which is `8` in your system

`sizeof(*ptr)` is giving you the size of the object referenced by the pointer `ptr`. As `ptr` is a pointer to the 2D array of `6` integers (3x2) then the size of that array is `24` bytes assuming the `sizeof(int) == 4`

Answer (score 0):

The *expression* `ptr` has type `int (*)[2][3]` (pointer to 2-element array of 3-element array of `int`) - it is a *pointer* type, so it's however big a pointer type is on your system (in this case, 8 bytes).

The expression `*ptr` has type `int [2][3]` - it's a 2x3 array of `int`, meaning it's big enough to store 6 `int` objects.  An `int` is 4 bytes wide on your system, for a total size of 24 bytes.

If the operand of `sizeof` is an expression instead of a type name, it goes by the *type* of the expression.  For example, the expression `1` has type `int`, the expression `2` has type `int`, and the expression `1 + 2` has type `int`, so

```
sizeof 1 == sizeof 2 == sizeof (1 + 2) == sizeof (int)
```

Remember that `sizeof` is an *operator*, not a function - you only need to use parentheses if the operand is a type name (like `(int)`) or if the operand is an expression containing operators of lower precedence.  For example

```
sizeof 1 + 2
```

will be parsed as

```
(sizeof 1) + 2
```

because the arithmetic `+` operator has lower precedence than the unary `sizeof` operator, which is probably not what you want.  However, expressions like

```
 sizeof *foo[N]
```

will be parsed as

```
 sizeof (*(foo[N]))
```

so parentheses aren't necessary in that case.  Some people will advise you to always use parentheses regardless, which isn't bad advice; eventually you'll learn when they aren't necessary and can be comfortable leaving them out.